# adding gridlines to boxplot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, gridlines

How do I add gridlines on both vertical and horizontal axis to a boxplot here is a simple example

```
load carsmall

boxplot(MPG, Origin, 'medianstyle', 'target')

grid on;
```

This only allows lines to be placed horizontally. I need something to separate out the horizontal axis as well
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `factorseparator` handle:

```
boxplot(MPG, Origin, 'medianstyle', 'target','factorseparator',1)
```

[image]

FYI, you would know that if you searched for the word "grid" in the boxplot documentation page http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html.
imagine what else you could discover if you start to read the documentation pages!